# How to fix width of a background image in any monitor resolution

Tags: html, css

I having a problem when I view my work in different PCs with different monitor resolution it stretching the the image.

How can I fix this?

```
.image-bg {
 background-image: url("assets/header.jpg");
 height:200px;
 width:100%;
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;}

<div class="image-bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `background-size:100% 100%;` to `background-size:100% auto;` which will **scale and crop** the image to fit your container size.

Here's a sample jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e7g0jknd/

In case you want the image to stick to the top and **span downwards**, you can use `background-position:50% 0;`:

https://jsfiddle.net/e7g0jknd/1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: although not perfectly fit atleast somehow help me thanks :D

Comment: Maybe you wanted to maintain the top of the image fixed? I will update the answer with an updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The image is stretching because you've specified a height. If you remove the `height` in your CSS your image shouldn't stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `background-size: cover` instead of `100% 100%` . It will resize propertionally vertically and horizontally read this resources http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp